# How to get `y_true` in the first place?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I see lots of posts and documentation where people are working with `y_true` as an argument for accuracy and metrics - almost as if it was callable from Keras.

> y_true: True labels. Theano/TensorFlow tensor.
>
> https://keras.io/metrics/#custom-metrics

If I wanted to call `keras.metrics.accuracy(y_true, y_pred)` myself, how would I get `y_true` without transforming my OHE'd `[0,1,0]` original `test_y` object back to categorical numbers? Can I somehow get it from `model` or another keras object?

Comment: Looks like I can `numpy.argmax(test_y, axis=1)` but wondering if I am missing something here.

Comment: Yup, that's how. It'll basically give the index of the column that has 1, which will be your class.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of what argmax is actually doing. Appreciate it.